# How to import data from Excel

Tags: angularjs, excel, d3.js, dc.js

I've got webApp to build a chart from an Excel file [***data.xls***] and ***d3.js***. Here's how I do it:

> **Step 1 >** Import file Excel by browse location (No local file)
>   **Step 2 >** Convert Excel file to data and pass to d3.js.

I using Wijmo.js to show Excel file and d3.js to build the chart, so I can only use an Excel file, no CSV!

Comment: cant you use csv? Excel allows you to save your files as csv

Comment: What is different?
I using from wijmo plugin, first show excel and second, convert to data for build chart in d3.js.

Comment: as per my understanding d3 can ingest data in csv, json and tsv formats. Havent come across any example where it is being used with a .xls file

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Excel.  When you save the spreadsheet, use the Save As dialog and select CSV as the "Save as Type"

[image]

Comment: thanks @Mr Smith, but I want use excel file, no csv file. D3.js can ingest data in csv, json and tsv formats

Comment: He is looking for ways to ingest xls data into d3. Converting to Csv is not a valid solution